# + isn't defined for the type 'Object

Tags: dart, object, operators, undefined, dart-null-safety

I keep getting this error => "The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (view docs). Try defining the operator '+'."

How could I define it?

```
    import 'dart:math';

bool isArmstrongNumber(int number) {
    var numberString = number.toString();

return number ==
    numberString.split("").fold(0,
        (prev, curr) => prev! + pow(int.parse(curr), numberString.length));
}                             

main() {
  var result = isArmstrongNumber(153);
  print(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fold` in Dart can have some problems when it comes to automatically determine what type it should return and handle. In these cases, we need to manually enter the type like this (`fold<int>()`):

```
import 'dart:math';

bool isArmstrongNumber(int number) {
  final numberString = number.toString();

  return number ==
      numberString.split("").fold<int>(
            0,
            (prev, curr) =>
                prev + pow(int.parse(curr), numberString.length).toInt(),
          );
}

void main() {
  final result = isArmstrongNumber(153);
  print(result); // true
}
```

I also fixed a problem where `pow` returns `num` which is a problem. In this case, we can safely just cast it to `int` without issues.

**Details about this problem with `fold`**

The problem here is that Dart tries to guess the generic of the `fold` based on the expected returned type of the method. Since the `==` operator expects an `Object` to compare against, `fold` will also expect to just return `Object` and the generic ends up being `fold<Object>`.

This is not a problem for the first parameter since `int` is an `Object`. But it becomes a problem with your second argument where you expect an `int` object and not `Object` since `Object` does not have the `+` operator.